# mongo db, compass - creating ttl index

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb

I need to delete documents in collection after 7 days from creation, unless "confirmed" value is equal true. I am creating index like on screenshot but it does not work. I am using Node.js for server if it matter.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: i think you need to try with cronjob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use rule npm package https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-rules to do this.
you can define a rule and if the rule is executed then the consequeces will be deleting the document. if the rule is to calculate the days count from the creation  date of the file
var RuleEngine = require("node-rules");

```
/* Creating Rule Engine instance */
var R = new RuleEngine();

/* Add a rule */
var rule = {
    "condition": (R) => {
        console.log(this);
        // check if a document creation date and current date , dates >= 7 
        // and check for other condition
    },
    "consequence": (R) => {
        // delete the document
        // if above condition met
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

you need cron job to achieve this
try something like this (I'm using [node-cron](https://github.com/kelektiv/node-cron) but you can use any cron job lib you want)

```
import cron  from 'node-cron'
import Collection from 'models/YourCollection'

cron.schedule('0 12 * * * *', () => { // execute everyday at 12:00
  const lastWeek = new Date();
  lastWeek.setDate(lastWeek.getDate() -7);
  Collection.deleteMany({'created_at': {'$lte': lastWeek}}) // created more than 7 days 
});
```

Comment: So there is no way to make it with indexes? I will write module code by myself than.

Comment: I think you cannot use multiple keys for TTL indexes. [ref](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-ttl/#restrictions)